# How do i allow a user to stay logged in in flutter in the safest way?

Tags: flutter

I want a user to stay logged in after closing the app. I've heard of shared preferences but most of the examples are for things not as important as users' login credentials so is it possible to use that package for this? Furthermore, is that a safe way to go about this problem? Or should i allow google sign in, in order to keep them signed in? I'm generally unsure about how i should go about doing this and which is the safest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go around this problem.

**1) Keeping login Data on the client side**

You can use Shared Pref. Once logged in you can save a value in shared Pref or in your db. When the user comes again you can check the value, if sharedpref says user is loggedIn, take user to HomeScreen else login screen.

**2) Keeping login data on your server.**

You can use a web API to make sure if user is loggedin. When user login for first time you can store loginStatus on server. when user kills app and come back again you check with an API. if user was loggedIn. If user was loggedIn, take user to HomeScreen else login screen.

**3) Using third Party APIs**

As you already mentioned Google Sign In. You can certainly leverage that. It is a powerful and clean API. But most importantly check it with your business requirement and compliance team.

Comment: Okay i would like to use shared preferences i think, but i don't understand how. I've look at the package page but the example is quite limited to help with my case. I understand the concept you described but how do i actually implement this. Do i need to create a new root page where it checks if user is logged in first and then goes to whatever page accordingly? Or should i somehow check inside the building of the sign in page? Do you know of any resources that would be helpful for this specific case? Thanks

Comment: You can have a [splash](http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html) page in starting showing your app logo and all. You can read the value from sharedPref and send it to the corresponding page accordingly. 
If you are not thinking of splash page, You can have an activity that has login and home page as fragments. You can decide in onCreate() on Activity and load fragment accordingly.  If you find this answer helpful please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yeah i got everything working now, but the only issue is that it shows the login page for like 1-2 seconds before signing them in automatically. Not really sure how splash pages work but that link is for just android/java not flutter